# How do I define variable inside bash -c?

Tags: bash

I want to define variable inside `bash -c` like following one. but the script outputs nothing. Any idea?

```
bash -c "FOOBARLIST=(foo bar) ; echo ${FOOBARLIST[@]} "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is not caused by the script you pass to `bash -c` but by the current instance of the shell (`bash` or whatever it is).

The script is an argument in a command line. Because it is enclosed in double quotes, the shell does variable expansion in it. It replaces `${FOOBARLIST[@]}` with the value of the `FOOBARLIST` array defined in the current environment.

But there isn't any `FOOBARLIST` variable in the current environment, `${FOOBARLIST[@]}` is replaced by an empty strings and the command it runs is:

```
bash -c "FOOBARLIST=(foo bar) ; echo "
```

The simplest solution is to enclose the script into single quotes (apostrophes). This way the current shell doesn't replace anything in it and passes it as is to `bash -c`:

```
bash -c 'FOOBARLIST=(foo bar); echo ${FOOBARLIST[@]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quotes here.

With double quotes, `${FOOBARLIST[@]}` is expanded by the outer shell before the inner shell even runs. Since `FOOBARLIST` is undefined in the outer shell, `${FOOBARLIST[@]}` expands to nothing and the inner shell executes:

```
FOOBARLIST=(foo bar) ; echo
```